# Woocommerce social login conflict with check out page "Returning customer? Click here to login" section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

http://herbaldispatch.com/checkout/

Please add a product and go to the checkout section of my site ,notice that Returning customer? Click here to login not working ,upon clicking the section opens up for a second ,then goes away .

I think  its a javascript conflict between these plugins as if i disable "woocommerce social login" it works , but i need to make it work with the wocommerce social login enabled .What can i do to achieve that?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** there is conflict in because of same class name `showlogin`.

If you open **wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > assets > js > frontend > checkout.min.js** and **wp-content > plugins > woocommerce-social-login > assets > js > frontend > wc-social-login.min.js ** and search for `showlogin`, you will find it in both opened file.

**Solution :**

What you can do is change class name of that link something like `<a href="#" class="show-login">Click here to login</a>` and change that class name in **wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > assets > js > frontend > checkout.min.js** as well like :

```
    a("a.show-login").click(function(){return a("form.login").slideToggle(),!1})
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply ,what i did : templates/checkout/form-login.php changed showlogin to show-login ,                                     and then  wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > assets > js > frontend > checkout.min.js showlogin to show-login ,just like you have mentioned ,no luck ,nothing happens if you click on the form .